# Python request - encoding form-data

Tags: python, python-requests

I would like to replicate following curl call in requests:

```
curl --request POST 'https://my_api.com/request/dynamic_views' \
--header 'Cookie: session=123' \
--form 'data="{\"searchId\":66966,\"mapAllTeam\":true}"'
```

I have a problem with form item which need to be provided as multipart/form-data.

I'm trying the following(simplified code):

```
uri="https://my_api.com/request/dynamic_views"
session_cookie = {"Cookie":"session=123"}
file = {"data": '"{\"searchId\":66966,\"mapAllTeam\":true }"'}

response = requests.post(uri, headers=session_cookie, files=file )
```

Response I got is:

```
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 400 \r\n'
[...]
{'status': 'Success', 'message': 'Missing required data, Please enter proper Data.'}
```

Which indicates that form has been incorrectly attached.

Answer (score 0):

It has to look like

```
files = {'data': (None,'{"searchId":66966,"mapAllTeam":true}')}
```